# symfony2 plug-ins comprehensive catalog

Tags: plugins, symfony

is there a comprehensive website for symfony2 plug-ins, so we could easily find tools for our needs - like it's with Ruby on Rails (`rubytoolbox` and `rubygems`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Symfony2 the "plugins" are called "bundles". You can find them all around the web, but one good source is http://knpbundles.com.

Answer (score 2):

Query [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) for symfony - though you can use non-symfony-strict libs in your project as well.